# Dataframe row items to column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame:

```
       type             result
0      IP_1         ['a', 'b']
1      IP_2         ['c', 'd']
```

I want it reshaped to look like this:

```
         IP_1           IP_2         
0  ['a', 'b']     ['c', 'd']
```

but when I try `df.pivot(columns='type', values='result')` I got:

```
             IP_1              IP_2
0             Nan        ['a', 'b']       
1      ['c', 'd']               NaN
```

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done it with a transpose

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {"type": "IP_1", "result": ['a', 'b']},
    {"type": "IP_2", "result": ['c', 'd']},
])
df = df.set_index('type').T
```

Output:

```
type      IP_1    IP_2
result  [a, b]  [c, d]
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use unstack as below:

```
df.unstack().unstack(level=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try transpose after changing index to type,

```
df.set_index("type").transpose().reset_index(drop=True)


type    IP_1    IP_2
0      [a, b]   [c, d]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have an the same index for both:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,["IP_1","['a', 'b']"],[2,"IP_2","['c', 'd']"]],columns=['ind','type','result'])
print(df.pivot(columns=['type'],index='ind'))

result            
type        IP_1        IP_2
ind                         
1     ['a', 'b']  ['c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your correctly you need to create create a new index then unstack based the position of each unique `type` value.

```
df.set_index([df.groupby("type").cumcount(), df["type"]])["result"].unstack()

type        IP_1        IP_2
0     ['a', 'b']  ['c', 'd']
```